# What is the impact of my dog having puppies?

Tags: dogs, health

I have a female dog, when she was little her birth did not go to plan, her mother was constantly used to being bred, I was thinking of breeding my dog once but one problem... I am too scared what will happen, this is what happened in her birth....

-My dog was found a hole in her heart

-She had fur but took longer to grow (when she was fully grown she had puppy fur still and looked like a hairless dog)

-She is a teacup (Small for her breed)

Do you think she will be safe and the puppies will? I know she will be a great mother but I am not sure if her and puppies will be healthy.
Such as if one of them will be ill.

(she is not pregnant but I want to make sure in case if I do breed her)

Comment: Responsible breeding involves evaluating how healthy both potential parents are, judging their temperment, health history, etc. Your dog had a rough start, and still has a heart issue. She sounds like a poor candidate to breed. So ask yourself why you want to do this. It is not going to make her life better or more fulfilled in any way.

Answer (score 4):

This is a very broad question and depends on many factors. To me it surely sounds like a case for concern, but even a strong, well fed, healthy bitch born from a strong, well fed, healthy mother can have abnormal pups or struggle during the process of giving birth. Things such as genetics also plays a role, which is also unknown. The likelihood that your veterinarian will advise against breeding just taking the history into consideration is high and so will I.

If you want a supported answer, Wikipedia has some interesting facts about Teacub dogs - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_dog

Very small dogs (adult or not), purely due to their size are prone to have problems when giving birth for various reasons. The mother and the puppies in these breeds are both in danger.

Comment: Well all the information I got from the breeders were... They were not kind to animals, constantly bred them, they had bacteria in their home (all 3 children were sick) and my dog was dying when she was a pup until I bought her. 

I don't trust Wikipedia and the fact that she is a teacup does not worry me as much, it's the fact she had a hole in her heart and was severely ill as a pup, I want to know if this is genetics and if she will be healthy and her puppies will be healthy too.

Comment: It probably is genetic. Knowing risk to the pups requires understanding exactly what genes are involved and how they would be likely to interact with the sire's genes. I'd advise talking to your vet, who knows that particular dog's history.